# Show/Hide fields (Conditional Logic) is not working in repeater field in php javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 radio buttons let's say  A,B,& C. when i click on the B a new section will come having some other form fields. and most important part is that i have to append/ repeat the entire part by an add more button and the whole functionality is as previous. but in the append filed the show hide function is not working.

Comment: It is mush easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as part of your question. It doesn't have to be the entire form.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to show a code snippet so it is easy for us to guide you. But try this code. Register the click event of the button using `$(document).on('click', 'element', function);`

```js
$(function(){
 $('#btnAddMore').on('click', function(){
        $(".repeater").append($('.template').html()); 
 });
 
  $(document).on('click', '[data-containerId="alertme"]', function(){
    alert("Hello world!");  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="template">
   <input type="submit" data-containerId="alertme" value="alert me" />
</div>
<div class="repeater">

</div><div>
  <button id="btnAddMore">add more</button>
</div>
```